# How to reduce resolution of adjacency matrix by grouping nodes

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix that expresses feeding links between species (column eats row)

```
mat1<-matrix(data=c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
                nrow=4, 
                ncol=4, 
                byrow = TRUE,
                dimnames = list(c("a","b","c","d"), 
                                c("a","b","c","d")))
```

I want to reduce the resolution of this matrix to family level using a dataframe that shows which family each species belongs to,

```
df <- data.frame(Species = c("a","b","c","d"), Family = c("E","E","F","F"))
```

so that the resulting matrix will give the number of feeding links between families

```
mat2<-matrix(data=c(0,2,1,0), 
            nrow=2, 
            ncol=2, 
            byrow = TRUE,
            dimnames = list(c("E","F"), 
                            c("E","F")))
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's the only way I know how, here's a solution using the tidyverse.
It turns the matrix into a long-form tibble, aggregates by family and then makes it wide again.

```
library(tidyverse)

# create a tibble that looks like the desired end-result matrix
df2 <- mat1 %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "Species_from") %>% # make a tibble
  pivot_longer(cols = -Species_from,
               names_to = "Species_to") %>% # turn into long form
  left_join(df, by = c("Species_from" = "Species")) %>% # add Family_from and Family_to
  left_join(df, by = c("Species_to" = "Species"), suffix = c("_from", "_to")) %>% 
  group_by(Family_from, Family_to) %>% # aggregate Family_from and Family_to
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% # ... by taking their sum
  pivot_wider(names_from = Family_to,
              values_from = value) # turn back into wide form

# turn into a matrix
mat2 <- as.matrix(df2[, c("E", "F")])
rownames(mat2) <- df2$Family_from

mat2

#   E F
# E 0 2
# F 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but here is an approach with `data.table`. If your adjacency matrix is very large, this may be faster than a pivot approach from `tidyr`.

First, we convert the two objects to `data.table`s. Then we join the `Family` onto the adjacency matrix. Then we sum each column by `Family` group. Finally, we transpose and do the same thing again.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dt <- as.data.table(cbind(Species = rownames(mat1),as.data.frame(mat1)))
a <- df[dt,on = "Species"][,-"Species"][,lapply(.SD, sum), by = Family]
b <- data.table::transpose(a, keep.names = "Family", make.names = 1)
setnames(b,"Family","Species")
c <- df[b,on = "Species"][,-"Species"][,lapply(.SD,sum), by = Family]
data.table::transpose(c, keep.names = "Family", make.names = 1)
   Family E F
1:      E 0 2
2:      F 1 0
```